# Call next() when the data is fetched

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, single-page-application

I'm using this npm package [vue-progressbar](https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-progressbar) but it shows the progress bar while the data in being fetched

What I wanna implement is for example when I click on some product I don't wanna leave my current route until the data in `ProductsShow` component is fetched then the progress bar will finish and call the `next()` method to head to the `ProductsShow` component's route

Is there anyways to do this? like to check if the data in the component of the route I'm heading to is fetched so I can finish the progress bar and call the `next()` method

Comment: Is it *mouting* you're waiting for? Or data-fetching you're waiting for? You tagged Axios which makes me wonder

Comment: Also, some code might help. Where in the component lifecycle are you triggering `this.$Progress.finish()`? Are you doing any other work in navigation guards for your `ProductsShow` component?

Comment: I'm waiting for data fetching. Must edit the title

Comment: I tried to implement this doing beforeEach but it didn't work out. Like I need to do some work in all components for this to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to do this you need to leverage `beforeRouteEnter` in your destination component, [similar to the Vue Router docs here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation).

```
<script>
export default {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    axios.get('/data/i/need')
      .then(function(response) {
        next(vm => {
          vm.myData = response.data // depends on the shape of your data and your destination component
        })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        next(false)  // or redirect to an error page?
      })
  }
}
</script>
```

If your route contains an id in the params, you can access it within beforeRouteEnter with `to.params.myIdValueOrWhatever`.